# MSFT_Volume Format Method, in WinPE

Tags: c#, wmi, winpe

I hope there may be some insight and maybe help in relation to my query.

I am trying to write the last module to a customised Windows Recovery environment, based on WinPE for Windows 10.

The solution currently utilises DiskPart to create the Disk Partitions (inline with Microsoft advice [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions)), with the change of not providing for the WinRE partition.

After a fair amount of research and tinkering with a project found on MSDN, I managed to get a working project that would clear/partition and format a disk using WMI (MSFT_Disk,MSFT_Partition & MSFT_Volume).  That is fully working within Windows 10 on a virtual disk of 15 GiB size.

When I tried it in WinPE (as this will be the OS that it will be used on), it failed on multiple elements, even though the Methods were reported as there). (MSFT_Disk::Clear, MSFT_Volume::Format).

On inspecting the result of my work in DiskPart, I noticed that even though MSFT_Volume::Format had a return value of 2 "Unknown Error" it had actually formatted the data partition (NTFS, ClusterSize 4096).  However, when when the Format method is applied to the ESP (FAT32, cluster size 512/1024/4096)it fails fully, with the FileSystem still being reported as RAW, but will apply an AccessPath.  "ExtendedStatus" only returns Error 2 (unless I am not accessing it correctly).

Has anyone else had this problem and managed to rectify the problem?  Multiple Google searches have thrown out the idea that there maybe a WMI error, but within PowerShell, not as coded in C#/C++.  Below are some code snippets and screen shots:

Creating the Partition:

```
try
{
    parameters = disk.GetMethodParameters("CreatePartition");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in Line 88: " + e.Message);
}
if (PartitionType != "PRIMARY")
{
    FillInvocationParameters(parameters, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Size", _partitionSize.ToString() },
                                                                          { "AssignDriveLetter", false },
                                                                          { "GpTType", _partitionType} });
} 
else
{
    FillInvocationParameters(parameters, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "UseMaximumSize", true },
                                                                          { "AssignDriveLetter", false },
                                                                          { "GpTType", _partitionType} });
}
try
{
    res = disk.InvokeMethod("CreatePartition", parameters, null);
    objresult = res["ReturnValue"]; //write error handliong routine for the objResult.
    Int32.TryParse(objresult.ToString(), out intRes);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Exception in Line 146: " + e.Message);
    ErrorID = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    return false;
}
if (intRes != 0)
{
    Console.Write("CreatePartition {0} failed with the result: {1} Line 111.", PartitionType, objresult.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
    ErrorID = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    return false;
}
//this is the format point for EFI System Disk.. MSFTPARTITIONtoVOLUME MSFT VOLUME::FORMAT

Console.Write($"{PartitionType} Partition has been created\r\n");

string partition   = ((ManagementBaseObject)res["CreatedPartition"])["__PATH"] as string;
var MSFT_Partition = new ManagementObject(@"root\Microsoft\Windows\Storage", partition, null);
var partitionIndex = partition.IndexOf(@"ObjectId=\");

partition      = partition.Substring(partitionIndex);
partitionIndex = partition.IndexOf(@"}\\");
partitionIndex = partitionIndex + 1;
partition      = partition.Substring(0, partitionIndex);

var strMSFTPartition = partition;
partition = partition.Replace("root", "ROOT");

var partitionGuid = MSFT_Partition["Guid"] as string;
Console.WriteLine("Line 138: New Partition GUID: " + partitionGuid);
```

Parameters is declared as:

```
 ManagementBaseObject parameters = null;
```

FillInvokationParamters:

```
private static void FillInvocationParameters(ManagementBaseObject InvocationParameters, IDictionary<string, object> parameters)
{
    foreach (var pair in parameters)
    {
        string stringParamValue;

        var managementObjectParam = pair.Value as ManagementObject;
        var arrayParam = pair.Value as string;

        if (managementObjectParam != null)
        {
            stringParamValue = managementObjectParam.GetText(TextFormat.CimDtd20);
            InvocationParameters[pair.Key] = stringParamValue;
        }
        else if (arrayParam != null)
            InvocationParameters[pair.Key] = arrayParam;
        else if (pair.Value != null)
        {
            stringParamValue = pair.Value.ToString();
            InvocationParameters[pair.Key] = stringParamValue;
        }
    }
}
```

And the Format Method call:

```
try
{
    Console.Write("Line 174: Attempting to Format with MSFT_Volume::Format FileSystem {0}, Label: {1}, ClusterSize: {2}\r\n", _FileSystem, _VolumeLable, _allocationUnit.ToString());
    parameters = MSFTVolume.GetMethodParameters("Format");

    FillInvocationParameters(parameters, new Dictionary<string, object>{ { "FileSystem", _FileSystem },
                                                                             { "AllocationUnitSize", _allocationUnit },
                                                                             { "FileSystemLabel", _VolumeLable },
                                                                             { "Full", false} });

    res = MSFTVolume.InvokeMethod("Format", parameters, null);
    objresult = res["ReturnValue"];

    Int32.TryParse(objresult.ToString(), out intReslt);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Line: 189 The Following error occured while attmpeting to Format the Volume: " + e.Message);
    ErrorID = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    return false;
}
```

For the ESP the following applies:

```
switch(PartitionType)
{
    case "EFI":
    {
        _partitionType  = "{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}";
        _partitionSize  = 260 /*bytes*/ *1024 /*Kilobytes*/ *1024 /*Megabytes*/;
        _FileSystem     = "FAT32";
        _allocationUnit = 1024;
        _VolumeLable    = "System";
        break;
    }
}
```

Screenshots of my console app and diskpart results:

[Format Disk Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpd4m.png)

[DiskPart Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVK2h.png)

Any help/insights will be gratefully appreciated.

Regards

Richie

Comment: Could you please advise how to format the code in a "better" way please.  This isn't my day job - but a project born out of having to purchase a new version of WIndows and Hard Drive, as it failed while I was out of the UK for a long period.  Not only am I relearning how to code, but an entire new language as well.

Comment: I would think common sense is that having everything indented 30 tabs makes it harder to read and looks awful. When you copy from your text editor to Stack Overflow, the tabs are copied over as well, so things tend to be way indented. You can use sharplab.io and use shift-tab to move it all over so its indented properly.

Comment: Thank you AustinWBryan - I'll keep that in mind, nice constructive criticism (with solution), this is what I need to help post in StackOverflow in the future.  Whoever posted about the code being awfully formatted and not providing a solution/pointing to a possible solution wasn't very help full.

Comment: Welcome. I edited the post to improve the formatting. That's how it should look next time. Also, side note, `return` isn't a function, so you don't need to do `return (false)`, just `return false`. And instead of `if (!(x == 3))` just do `if (x != 3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that there are several builds of the ADK for newer builds of Windows 10...be sure to use the latest and greatest. We had issues similar to yours with both dism.exe and diskpart.exe. At one point, (on early win 10 adks) we got dism.exe and diskpart.exe from an 8.1 adk. Hacky as heck, but you gotta do what you gotta do :-)

**Update**:

Checked with the support group...turns out, I got the versions mixed up. The very first win 10 adk had a working dism and diskpart (adk for windows 10 1503)...and we've been unable to use *newer* ones from within PE since...and so we're still deploying a new winpe from new ADK - but copying in the diskpart and dism saved off from the 1503 adk. We never deployed 8.1 versions - my bad. Still - hacky as all git out.

Best we can recollect, it only presented a problem in one side of the house...either BIOS+MBR or UEFI+GPT...but none of us remember which.

Comment: I have tried to use the latest version of the ADK, it broke the build.  I haven't retried to use it as yet, as essentially the software works with DiskPart.  I have a feeling that it may well be a test environment issue - so am currently remote booting an old laptop to see if the issue represents itself again.  If it does then I know it is an issue with Virtual Box.

Comment: Have examined my console output, both the VM and live remote booted system report the EFI Partition as USB Store (either that,or the USB Disk has the same GUID for some reason!).  When I am iterating/enumerating through the WMI MSFT_Volume's and really tie down the comparison string it works finds the volume but returns Error Code 2 "Unspecified Error".

Comment: It seems as though it was the build of WinPE.  I managed to build a working WinPE (version 1803) - with no tweaks, the test bed application worked - but requires max power to be set on the system first.  Now to design and implement a CallBack routine to integrate results into the GUI - without changing the base code.

Thanks Clay.

Comment: Excellent - 1803 is working clean for us, too. Your question prompted us to try dropping the hacky dism/diskpart insertion...and everything is working fine here, too...so thanks yerseff!

Comment: I'm trying to move away from Diskpart, already moved away from DISM - I have managed to implement the wimgapi in C# (well a small number of functions to allow what I want to do).  

I'm not at the full capability for the suite yet - so not everything is implemented.  Next stage after integrating WMI Disk Management is to build a more robust entry for remote boot and access to the Source images.

Comment: I believe the underlying implementation of diskpart is the same regardless of whether you come at it through wmi or through diskpart scripting...and is mostly why I predicted you'd get success with a fixed winpe :-)  Funny enough, we only use dism to put a persistent winpe in its own partition at the beginning of an imaging cycle. We have our own very de-duplicated image database that shares shards with all of the enterprise images. It has slowly become very cool. We looked at wimgapi - but went 100% weird...part of how we differentiate ourselves. Peace!

Comment: That's how this project started, failed hard drive (no given warnings).  I started with ImageX (going back some - tried to port it into Pascal - but gave up when I stated having to define too much), then DISM as the scripted.  Started to play with wimgapi just shy of a year ago.  Thanks for your pointers, glad that my question encouraged you to take a new look at your WinPE distro.